# zmq_bind segfault for tcp & ipc

Tags: c++, zeromq

In working with the zmq library in C/C++, the following code produces a segmentation fault on the bind command.  Using ZMQ v4.2.5 (currently the latest stable release).  Below is the relevant code for the connection: creating the context, the socket, and binding the socket (which is the trouble line).

```
cout << "Creating the context" << endl;
void* ctx = zmq_ctx_new();
if (ctx == NULL)
{
    cout << "Context was null!" << endl;
    cout << "ZMQ Error code: " << zmq_strerror(zmq_errno()) << endl;
    return -1;
}
else cout << "Address of the context: " << ctx << endl;

cout << "Creating the socket now" << endl;
void* socket = zmq_socket(ctx, ZMQ_DEALER);
if (socket == NULL)
{
    cout << "Socket was null!" << endl;
    cout << "ZMQ Error code: " << zmq_strerror(zmq_errno()) << endl;
    return -1;
}
else cout << "Socket created! Address of the socket: " << socket << endl;

const char[] addr = "ipc://test";
cout << "Binding the socket now: " << addr << endl;
int rc = zmq_bind(socket, addr); // <-- SegFault Line
if (rc != 0)
{
    cout << "ERROR BINDING THE SOCKET!" << endl;
    cout << "ZMQ Error code: " << zmq_strerror(zmq_errno()) << endl;
    return -1;
}
else cout << "Socket successfully bound" << endl;
```

Additional information:

- binding the socket works with `inproc`, but causes the segmentation fault with `ipc` or `tcp`
- user has appropriate permissions to write to the folder (for ipc sockets)
- Valgrind returns a `bad permissions for mapped region` error in the zmq code pointing at the `set_address` function

  - Error still persists if passing in literal string as the argument (as opposed to `addr` variable)
- Running on Centos 7.5 with KDE

Thank you for your time.

Edit: Added OS information in the Additional Information section

Comment: I tested your code (copy and paste) and it works fine. You should look into your system configuration. Could it be you don't have permission to open socket ?

Comment: I've given full access permission to the folder and executed with sudo without any luck. Is there another system configuration that I could look at for these permissions?

Comment: `bad permissions for mapped region` could indicate a stack overflow so maybe check ulimit options : size of heap, stack, POSIX message queues etc...